# How can I set two anchors with different widths and the same height using PyTorch’s AnchorGenerator module?

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, torchvision

I’m trying to use the AnchorGenerator module in PyTorch, but I’m having trouble setting up two anchors with different widths and the same height. Specifically, I want one anchor to have a height of 43 and a width of 10, and the other anchor to have a height of 43 and a width of 20. How can I achieve this?